# JPA CAN_NOT_JOIN_TO_BASIC

Tags: java, jpa

I have two tables: `User` and `Event` in a many-to-many relationship. For this I have used a 3rd table, `UserEvent` which has some additional columns. That is why in JPA I have the following relationships:

for Event:

`@Id @GeneratedValue int id;`

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="event")
    private List<UserEvent> users;`

for User:

`@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;`

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserEvent> events;`

for UserEvent:

```
@IdClass(UserEventPK.class)
public class UserEvent {
@Id
private int userId;
@Id
private int eventId;
    @ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="ID")
private UserAccountModel user;

@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="eventId", referencedColumnName="ID")
private EventModel event;
    }
```

I am trying to get all events where `UserEvent.user_id == id` using Criteria:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Event> criteria = criteriaBuilder
            .createQuery(Event.class);
    Root<Event> root = criteria.from(Event.class);
    criteria.select(root);
    criteria.distinct(true);
    Join<Event, UserEvent> user = root.join("id", JoinType.INNER);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    if (id > 0) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(user.get("userId"), id));
    }
    if (predicates.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("no criteria");
    } else if (predicates.size() == 1) {
        criteria.where(predicates.get(0));
    } else {
        criteria.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates
                .toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    }
    TypedQuery<Event> q = em.createQuery(criteria);
    if (id > 0) {
        q.setParameter("userId", id);
    }
    List<EventModel> results = q.getResultList();
```

I get the following error at the `Join`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CAN_NOT_JOIN_TO_BASIC (There is no English translation for this message.)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.FromImpl.join(FromImpl.java:355)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.FromImpl.join(FromImpl.java:512)
at com.maze.service.EventService.getList(EventService.java:86)
at test.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:40)
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A join must always be done on an association. The association between Event and UserEvent is mapped by the field `users`. So this is the field that you must use to create your join:

```
Join<Event, UserEvent> user = root.join("users", JoinType.INNER);
```

Comment: Using the canonical Metamodel:

    Join<Event, UserEvent> user = root.join(Event_.users, JoinType.INNER);